# Upload image submission

Tags: javascript, html, image, file, upload

I have found a great [text-editor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content#Example_A_simple_but_complete_rich_text_editor)

and I start making so many modification on it so i can use it on my website and i wanted to add upload image option so added this script to it

```js
function readURL(){
    var file = document.getElementById("uploadbutton").files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(){
           var imgg = document.createElement("img");imgg.src=reader.result;
        document.getElementById("textBox").appendChild(imgg); 
    }
    if(file){
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }else{
    }
}
```

```html
<input type='file' id='uploadbutton' accept="image/*" onclick='readURL()'/>
```

But when i try to upload image I face two problems :
1 - To upload image to text-editor I need to click on upload image to upload and click on upload image again to submit the image .
2 - the image does not get upload in the specific place in the text where i want (in the text cursor place)

and this is the whole script of the text-editor [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/talabe/zopu5jag/)

```js
var oDoc, sDefTxt;

function initDoc() {
  oDoc = document.getElementById("textBox");
  sDefTxt = oDoc.innerHTML;
  if (document.compForm.switchMode.checked) { setDocMode(true); }
}

function formatDoc(sCmd, sValue) {
  if (validateMode()) { document.execCommand(sCmd, false, sValue); oDoc.focus(); }
}

function validateMode() {
  if (!document.compForm.switchMode.checked) { return true ; }
  alert("Uncheck \"Show HTML\".");
  oDoc.focus();
  return false;
}

function setDocMode(bToSource) {
  var oContent;
  if (bToSource) {
    oContent = document.createTextNode(oDoc.innerHTML);
    oDoc.innerHTML = "";
    var oPre = document.createElement("pre");
    oDoc.contentEditable = false;
    oPre.id = "sourceText";
    oPre.contentEditable = true;
    oPre.appendChild(oContent);
    oDoc.appendChild(oPre);
    document.execCommand("defaultParagraphSeparator", false, "div");
  } else {
    if (document.all) {
      oDoc.innerHTML = oDoc.innerText;
    } else {
      oContent = document.createRange();
      oContent.selectNodeContents(oDoc.firstChild);
      oDoc.innerHTML = oContent.toString();
    }
    oDoc.contentEditable = true;
  }
  oDoc.focus();
}




function printDoc() {
 if (!validateMode()) { return; }
var printContents = document.getElementById('textBox').innerHTML;
var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = printContents+'<div style="width:150px;position:fixed;bottom:5px;right:5px;opacity:.5;">Display Logo Here...</div>';
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}



/*page margin*/
var cssPagedMedia = (function () {
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    return function (rule) {
        style.innerHTML = rule;
    };
}());

cssPagedMedia.margin = function (margin) {
    cssPagedMedia('@page {margin: ' + margin + '}');
};

cssPagedMedia.margin('0');
/*page size*/
cssPagedMedia.size = function (size) {
    cssPagedMedia('@page {size: ' + size + '}');
};

var cssPagedMedia = (function () {
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    return function (rule) {
        style.innerHTML = rule;
    };
}());

cssPagedMedia.size = function (size) {
    cssPagedMedia('@page {size: ' + size + '}');
};

cssPagedMedia.size('portrait');
//image upload
function readURL(){
    var file = document.getElementById("uploadbutton").files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(){
           var imgg = document.createElement("img");imgg.src=reader.result;
        document.getElementById("textBox").appendChild(imgg); 
    }
    if(file){
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }else{
    }
}
```

```css
.intLink { cursor: pointer; }
img.intLink { border: 0; }
#toolBar1 select { font-size:10px; }
#textBox {

  width: 540px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px #000000 solid;
  padding: 12px;
  overflow: scroll;
  
}
#textBox #sourceText {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 498px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.unselectable {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
 cursor: not-allowed;
}

#editMode label { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div id="printa">
<body onload="initDoc();">
<form name="compForm" method="post" action="sample.php" onsubmit="if(validateMode()){this.myDoc.value=oDoc.innerHTML;return true;}return false;">
<input type="hidden" name="myDoc">
<div id="toolBar1">
<select onchange="formatDoc('formatblock',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
<option selected>- التنسيق -</option>
<option value="h1">عنوان 1 &lt;h1&gt;</option>
<option value="h2">عنوان 2 &lt;h2&gt;</option>
<option value="h3">عنوان 3 &lt;h3&gt;</option>
<option value="h4">عنوان 4 &lt;h4&gt;</option>
<option value="h5">عنوان 5 &lt;h5&gt;</option>
<option value="h6">عنوان فرعي &lt;h6&gt;</option>
<option value="p">فقرة &lt;p&gt;</option>
<option value="pre">مهيأ مسبقا &lt;pre&gt;</option>
</select>
<select onchange="formatDoc('fontname',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
<option class="heading" selected>- الخطوط -</option>
<option>Arial</option>
<option>Arial Black</option>
<option>Courier New</option>
<option>Times New Roman</option>
</select>
<select onchange="formatDoc('fontsize',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
<option class="heading" selected>- الحجم -</option>
<option value="1">صغير جدا</option>
<option value="2">صغير بعض الشيء</option>
<option value="3">عادي</option>
<option value="4">متوسط - كبير</option>
<option value="5">كبير</option>
<option value="6">كبير جدا</option>
<option value="7">أقصى</option>
</select>
<select onchange="formatDoc('forecolor',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
<option class="heading" selected>- اللون -</option>
<option value="red">أحمر</option>
<option value="blue">أزرق</option>
<option value="green">أخضر</option>
<option value="black">أسود</option>
</select>
<select onchange="formatDoc('backcolor',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
<option class="heading" selected>- الخلفية -</option>
<option value="red">أحمر</option>
<option value="green">أخضر</option>
<option value="black">أسود</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="toolBar2">

<input type='file' id='uploadbutton' accept="image/*" onclick='readURL()'/>
   
<img class="intLink" title="طباعة" onclick="printDoc();" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
<img class="intLink" title="خط عريض " onclick="formatDoc('bold');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAInhI+pa+H9mJy0LhdgtrxzDG5WGFVk6aXqyk6Y9kXvKKNuLbb6zgMFADs=" />
<img class="intLink" title="خط مائل" onclick="formatDoc('italic');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAKEDAAAAAF9vj5WIbf///yH5BAEAAAMALAAAAAAWABYAAAIjnI+py+0Po5x0gXvruEKHrF2BB1YiCWgbMFIYpsbyTNd2UwAAOw==" />
<img class="intLink" title="تسطير" onclick="formatDoc('underline');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAKECAAAAAF9vj////////yH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAWABYAAAIrlI+py+0Po5zUgAsEzvEeL4Ea15EiJJ5PSqJmuwKBEKgxVuXWtun+DwxCCgA7" />
<img class="intLink" title="محاذاة إلى اليسار" onclick="formatDoc('justifyleft');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAIghI+py+0Po5y02ouz3jL4D4JMGELkGYxo+qzl4nKyXAAAOw==" />
<img class="intLink" title="محاذاة إلى الوسط" onclick="formatDoc('justifycenter');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAIfhI+py+0Po5y02ouz3jL4D4JOGI7kaZ5Bqn4sycVbAQA7" />
<img class="intLink" title="محاذاة إلى اليمين" onclick="formatDoc('justifyright');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAIghI+py+0Po5y02ouz3jL4D4JQGDLkGYxouqzl43JyVgAAOw==" />
<img class="intLink" title="الرجوع إلى الخلف" onclick="formatDoc('undo');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAOMKADljwliE33mOrpGjuYKl8aezxqPD+7/I19DV3NHa7P///////////////////////yH5BAEKAA8ALAAAAAAWABYAAARR8MlJq7046807TkaYeJJBnES4EeUJvIGapWYAC0CsocQ7SDlWJkAkCA6ToMYWIARGQF3mRQVIEjkkSVLIbSfEwhdRIH4fh/DZMICe3/C4nBQBADs=" />
<img class="intLink" title="التقدم إلى الأمام" onclick="formatDoc('redo');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAMIHAB1ChDljwl9vj1iE34Kl8aPD+7/I1////yH5BAEKAAcALAAAAAAWABYAAANKeLrc/jDKSesyphi7SiEgsVXZEATDICqBVJjpqWZt9NaEDNbQK1wCQsxlYnxMAImhyDoFAElJasRRvAZVRqqQXUy7Cgx4TC6bswkAOw==" />
<img class="intLink" title="قائمة ذات تعداد رقمي" onclick="formatDoc('insertorderedlist');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAMIGAAAAADljwliE35GjuaezxtHa7P///////yH5BAEAAAcALAAAAAAWABYAAAM2eLrc/jDKSespwjoRFvggCBUBoTFBeq6QIAysQnRHaEOzyaZ07Lu9lUBnC0UGQU1K52s6n5oEADs=" />
<img class="intLink" title="قائمة ذات تعداد نقطي" onclick="formatDoc('insertunorderedlist');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAMIGAAAAAB1ChF9vj1iE33mOrqezxv///////yH5BAEAAAcALAAAAAAWABYAAAMyeLrc/jDKSesppNhGRlBAKIZRERBbqm6YtnbfMY7lud64UwiuKnigGQliQuWOyKQykgAAOw==" />
<img class="intLink" title="إضافة رابط" onclick="var sLnk=prompt('Write the URL here','http:\/\/');if(sLnk&&sLnk!=''&&sLnk!='http://'){formatDoc('createlink',sLnk)}" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAOMKAB1ChDRLY19vj3mOrpGjuaezxrCztb/I19Ha7Pv8/f///////////////////////yH5BAEKAA8ALAAAAAAWABYAAARY8MlJq7046827/2BYIQVhHg9pEgVGIklyDEUBy/RlE4FQF4dCj2AQXAiJQDCWQCAEBwIioEMQBgSAFhDAGghGi9XgHAhMNoSZgJkJei33UESv2+/4vD4TAQA7" />
<img class="intLink" title="القص" onclick="formatDoc('cut');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQSAB1ChBFNsRJTySJYwjljwkxwl19vj1dusYODhl6MnHmOrpqbmpGjuaezxrCztcDCxL/I18rL1P///////////////////////////////////////////////////////yH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAVu4CeOZGmeaKqubDs6TNnEbGNApNG0kbGMi5trwcA9GArXh+FAfBAw5UexUDAQESkRsfhJPwaH4YsEGAAJGisRGAQY7UCC9ZAXBB+74LGCRxIEHwAHdWooDgGJcwpxDisQBQRjIgkDCVlfmZqbmiEAOw==" />
<img class="intLink" title="النسخ" onclick="formatDoc('copy');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQcAB1ChBFNsTRLYyJYwjljwl9vj1iE31iGzF6MnHWX9HOdz5GjuYCl2YKl8ZOt4qezxqK63aK/9KPD+7DI3b/I17LM/MrL1MLY9NHa7OPs++bx/Pv8/f///////////////yH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAWG4CeOZGmeaKqubOum1SQ/kPVOW749BeVSus2CgrCxHptLBbOQxCSNCCaF1GUqwQbBd0JGJAyGJJiobE+LnCaDcXAaEoxhQACgNw0FQx9kP+wmaRgYFBQNeAoGihCAJQsCkJAKOhgXEw8BLQYciooHf5o7EA+kC40qBKkAAAGrpy+wsbKzIiEAOw==" />
<img class="intLink" title="اللصق" onclick="formatDoc('paste');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQUAD04KTRLY2tXQF9vj414WZWIbXmOrpqbmpGjudClFaezxsa0cb/I1+3YitHa7PrkIPHvbuPs+/fvrvv8/f///////////////////////////////////////////////yH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAWN4CeOZGmeaKqubGsusPvBSyFJjVDs6nJLB0khR4AkBCmfsCGBQAoCwjF5gwquVykSFbwZE+AwIBV0GhFog2EwIDchjwRiQo9E2Fx4XD5R+B0DDAEnBXBhBhN2DgwDAQFjJYVhCQYRfgoIDGiQJAWTCQMRiwwMfgicnVcAAAMOaK+bLAOrtLUyt7i5uiUhADs=" />
<img class="intLink" title="المسح التام" onclick="if(validateMode()&&confirm('Are you sure?')){oDoc.innerHTML=sDefTxt};" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQbAD04KTRLYzFRjlldZl9vj1dusY14WYODhpWIbbSVFY6O7IOXw5qbms+wUbCztca0ccS4kdDQjdTLtMrL1O3YitHa7OPcsd/f4PfvrvDv8Pv5xv///////////////////yH5BAEKAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAV84CeOZGmeaKqubMteyzK547QoBcFWTm/jgsHq4rhMLoxFIehQQSAWR+Z4IAyaJ0kEgtFoLIzLwRE4oCQWrxoTOTAIhMCZ0tVgMBQKZHAYyFEWEV14eQ8IflhnEHmFDQkAiSkQCI2PDC4QBg+OAJc0ewadNCOgo6anqKkoIQA7" />

</div>
<iframe id="inlineFrameExample" name="inlineFrameExample" title="Inline Frame Example" width="0" height="0" dir="rtl" hidden="hidden">
  </iframe>
<div id="textBox" contenteditable="true" >


<div style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/KDXSnOv.jpg" width="160"></div><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span>
</div> 

<p id="editMode"><input type="checkbox" name="switchMode" id="switchBox" onchange="setDocMode(this.checked);" hidden="hidden"/> </p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send" hidden="hidden" /></p>
```